# Windows translate external IPv6 to localhost IPv4

Tags: windows, nat, ipv6, tunneling, ipv4

I have a machine running Windows server 2012, whose external IPv6 address is "2a01:4f8:190:7449::4". Let's assume it has no external IPv4 address, so the v6 address is the only way of accessing it from outside. But I have services running which are not compatible with IPv6. I want the machine to forward incoming traffic on "2a01:4f8:190:7449::4" to "127.0.0.1", and back. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll want a HTTP proxy that runs on windows *and* speaks IPv4/IPv6.  However, the premise is somewhat absurd -- at the very least you could give it an IPv4 address on the internal private network and arrange for IPv4 SNAT on your router...

Comment: I need this to work for any TCP or UDP port, not just HTTP.

Comment: Then you *definitely* want SNAT

Answer (score 0):

The technology you're looking for is called [NAT64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64). Note that this will generally run on a router upstream of your IPv4-only service, rather than on the server itself. What to use to implement NAT64, and where in your network to put it, is going to depend on your existing network architecture and the services that need to be accessed using it.

Speaking of those services, if at all possible, they should be made IPv6-capable, or replaced.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work because I have a single dedicated server, not a whole network and a router.

Comment: You need to fix the service, then, whatever it is. As far as I know there is no NAT64 implementation for Windows.